# Are members value initialized before the constructor initializer list executes?

Tags: c++

Take this example:

```
class Foo {
private:
  const std::string m_str1;
  const std::string m_str2;

  std::string foo() {
    std::cout << ("'" + m_str2 + "'") << std::endl;
    return "whatever1";
  }

public:
  Foo() : m_str1(foo()), m_str2("whatever2") { }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  return 0;
}
```

On my computer, it prints out '' (two single quotes one after another) indicating that m_str2 was in fact value initialized to the empty string before the constructor list was executed.

But is that true in general?

Comment: They're initialized (at least `std::string` is) in the order of declaration in the class during the initializer list.

Comment: @chris yes, that's why i organized my code the way i do, namely making foo() output the contents of m_str2, before m_str2 is actually initialized.

Comment: @chris Could this be undefined behavior? `m_str2`'s constructor isn't yet called when it's used in `foo()`.

Comment: @MarkGarcia, Yes, it's uninitialized at that point, unless there's some other happening I never knew about.

Comment: Yes, the behavior is undefined. On my computer, for example, the output is either "`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
Aborted (core dumped)`" or "`Use of uninitialised value of size 8 at 0x4EED723: std::string::size() const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)`".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As chris commented, the construction of `Foo` will, **in order**:

- initialize `m_str1`
- initialize `m_str2`
- run the (empty) constructor body

You are observing that during the initialization of `m_str1`, `m_str2` has not been initialized yet.

`m_str2` has **not** been value initialized to the empty string, as you say.

Accessing `m_str2` at that time is **[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**.

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior.  `m_str2` is not yet constructed when `foo()` is called.  The fact that it seems to work is probably coincidental.